# Anyone knows the second icon?

Tags: notification-icons, menu

Thanks very much for explaining !![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That N-shaped notification represents NFC, which normally appears when its turned on.

> NFC, or Near Field Communication, is a technology that allows devices
>   to exchange information simply by placing them next to one another.

Read more [here](https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/mobile-phone/how-make-n-symbol-on-your-android-phone-go-away-3628010/):

Comment: @WopkePostuma-Bijl if that answered your question to your satisfaction, please "[accept](/help/someone-answers)" it by ticking the check-mark next to it.